# Escape a json string to hex notation

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I store a JSON object using Google apps script properties service, and would like to send that object as hex escaped JSON string to client page using templated html service.

At server side

```
var str= '{ "test": "hello" }'; //how do I send a hex escaped string 
var test = JSON.parse(str);
console.dir(test);
```

Expected string in client page
ie, the str object (view html source) in the client side should be read as

```
var str= "{\x22test\x22: \x22hello\x22}";
var test = JSON.parse(str);
console.dir(test);
```

Comment: Is it only the spaces that you want to hex escape? What is the reason you need such escaping?

Comment: "{ test: 'he'llo' }" will be made as {\x22test\x22: \x22he'llo\x22} without throwing error, if the values itself has JSON chars

Comment: I want the JSON chars to escape without the actual values

Comment: I corrected to var str= '{ "test": "hello" }';,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is replace the quotes you can use a simple replacement like this

```js
var str= '{ "test": "hello" }';

var strEscaped = str.replace(/"/g, '\\x22')
console.dir(strEscaped);
```

However this does not deal with quotes inside values, they would also be replaced.

If the issue you are facing has to do with encoding in transfer it might be better for you to convert the whole string to [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) before transmitting and then decode it back from base64 before use. This is super easy to do in JavaScript and on most other platforms:

```js
var str = '{ "test": "hello" }';
var encoded = btoa(str);
console.dir('encoded:');
console.log(encoded);

console.log();
var decoded = atob(encoded);
console.log('decoded');
console.log(decoded);
```